# How to handle textbox selection start property in vb.net or c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

When i am assigning text in to textbox that time the selection start property is zero
so the cursor(caret) is moving to first location of the textbox.
How to solve this problem?

Code Sample

Consider that the textbox already have text like 'Hello Developers'

```
    Dim CurPosition As Integer = TextBox1.SelectionStart
    'CurPosition=11 (i.e) SelectionStart is 11 (cursor position)'


    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Remove(5, 11)
    'After Assigning Text the selectionStart is 0 (cursor position)'

    TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.TextLength
    'Here After the selectionstart is 5'

    TextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
```

so when i am executing this code the cursor move up and down so how to solve this problem.

Comment: I really don't have a clue what you're asking. Based on the comments in your code, it seems to be doing what I'd expect your code to do. Can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: You just click the link i clearly explain the concept. what is My Problem and what is my requirement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115199/textbox-keypress-event-using-vb-net-or-c

Answer (score 1):

I think I don't really know what's your problem.

But I think you could assign the selectionstart-property after scrolltocaret() again or just use the select() method.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that your the Caret dosnt appear within the text box?  If so try:

```
 Dim CurPosition As Integer = TextBox1.SelectionStart
 'CurPosition=11 (i.e) SelectionStart is 11 (cursor position)'


 TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Remove(5, 11)
 'After Assigning Text the selectionStart is 0 (cursor position)'

 TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.TextLength
 'Here After the selectionstart is 5'

 TextBox1.ScrollToCaret()

 TextBox1.Focus()
```

Comment: my requirement is i am trying to develop a text editor for my mother tongue language. that is i am trying to develop tamil text editor using unicode characters. where i am pressing English character like k that time i want to replace two characters like "&H0b95" "&H0bcd". how to i implement this concept? whether it is possible or not.  sample code when keypress event e.keychar=     chrw("&H0b95") & chrw("&H0bcd").

Comment: Sorry I still don't fully understand what your trying to do.  Are you trying to get Caret to return to its position it was at before the Remove function was called?

Comment: My Problem is the cursor position is moving. how to stop the moving. that is when assigning the text that time selection start is zero. how to stop that is selectionstart property don't change. How to done time. For Example when u typing the text the cursor(caret) moving forward only. But my problem is the cursor is scrolling that is when i am pressing a key cursor move up and set selectionstart then cursor at end of the text.

Comment: You just click the link i clearly explain the concept. what is My Problem and what is my requirement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115199/textbox-keypress-event-using-vb-net-or-c