# Textbox_KeyPress Event using vb.net or c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

My requirement is i am trying to develop a text editor for my mother tongue language. 
That is i am trying to develop tamil text editor using unicode characters. 
When i am pressing key on the keyboard(English character like) k that time i want to replace two characters like "&H0b95" "&H0bcd". 
How to i implement this concept? whether it is possible or not.
sample code when keypress event

```
 e.keychar=chrw("&H0b95") & chrw("&H0bcd") 'This code is not Execute Becuase it get Only One Character'

 TextBox1.Text=chrw("&H0b95") & chrw("&H0bcd")
```

I am already finish this concept but the only problem is cursor position is scroll that is when i am assigning the character to textbox that time selection start is zero so the cursor go to first position. after second line i am set the cursor position to the length of the text that is cursor come to end of the text.

so the problem is the cursor move up and down when i am pressing a key at all the times. how to solve this problem. can any body given an idea to me.

Click [here](http://www.jodelpeter.de/i18n/tamil/xref-uc.htm)! To See the Tamil Unicode Characters Table.

Comment: What UI do you use? WinForms of WPF?

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the textbox from rendering, while you update the cursor position. I had done something similar before with a console application. But can't find the code to reference it here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the SelectionStart Property and increase its length with the size of the new text inserted.
Something like:

```
int curPos = txtEditor.SelectionStart;
if (e.KeyChar == 'k')
{
    txtEditor.Text=txtEditor.Text.Insert(txtEditor.SelectionStart, "jj");
    txtEditor.SelectionLength = 0;
}
txtEditor.SelectionStart = curPos + 2; //or whatever the length of text u inserted
```

Answer (score -1):

this TextBox, adds "jj" when the user presses k key. The cursor position is corrcted.

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.K)
        {
            int pos = this.SelectionStart;
            this.Text = this.Text.Substring(0, this.SelectionStart) + "jj" 
            + this.Text.Substring(this.SelectionStart);
            this.SelectionStart = pos + 2;
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Coding also the same problem that is second time you press k that time selectionstart=2 when you assign the text that time it is zero. so same problem occured.