# textbox Insert and remove function in vb.net or c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

How to update the text from the `TextBox` control?

Consider a `TextBox` that already contains the string "Wel"

To insert text in the `TextBox`, I use:

```
   TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Insert(3, "come")
```

And to remove characters from the `TextBox`:

```
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Remove(3, 4)
```

But I need to be able to do this:

```
    TextBox1.Text.Insert(3, "come");
    TextBox1.Text.Remove(3, 4);
```

However, this code doesn't update the `TextBox`.

It this possible?

Can this be accomplished via the append method?

Comment: Please ellaborate your question.

Comment: Click the link to get the details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115199/textbox-keypress-event-using-vb-net-or-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Text` property of TextBox is of type string which is immutable it's not possible to change the existing string. `Insert()` or `Remove()` returns a new instance of string with the modification and you will have to assign this new instance back to TextBox's Text property.

There is `TextBox.AppendText()` that you might be interested in. It appends text to the end of the string but you cannot do anything like `Insert()` or `Remove()` with it though.

EDIT:

for your keypress, you could do something like this

```
        char charToReplace = (char) (e.KeyChar + 1);    // substitute replacement char
        textBox1.SelectedText = new string(charToReplace,1);
        e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: Using AppendText To Remove the characters from the textbox?

Comment: @Balachandran nope. You cannot remove chars with `AppendText()`.

Comment: then what i do? My problem is when assign the text to textbox that time the cursor move to 0th position. After that i set selectionstart property it goes to end of the text. But i am write the code in the keypress event. so every key press the cursor is scrolling.

Comment: @Balachandran you need to work with `SelectionStart` and `SelectionText`. If you can explain exactly what you are trying to do in keypress, someone might be able to help.

Comment: click the link i explain my requirements. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115199/textbox-keypress-event-using-vb-net-or-c

Comment: @Balachandran Checkout my edit to see if you can use it for your keypress event handler.

Comment: Thanks Bala it is very useful. Thank you verymuch. Good Night.

Answer (score 0):

`'string'` is a immutable type, so each time string value changes new memory is allocated. So if you want to insert or remove text from `TextBox`, you have to assign it back to `TextBox.Text` property. However, if you just want to append text to the `TextBox.Text`, you can do

```
textBox.AppendText("Hello");
```

Comment: My problem is when assign the text to textbox that time the cursor move to 0th position. After that i set selectionstart property it goes to end of the text. But i am write the code in the keypress event. so every key press the cursor is scrolling.